# for_each on a reverse_iterator of a custom bidirectional iterator requires OutputIterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, reverse-iterator

I created a simple *immutable* bidirectional iterator:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class my_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, int
//, std::ptrdiff_t, int*, int
> {
  int d_val;
public:
  my_iterator() : d_val(0) {}
  my_iterator(int val) : d_val(val) {}

  my_iterator  operator--(int) { d_val--; return my_iterator(d_val + 1); }
  my_iterator &operator--()    { d_val--; return *this; }
  my_iterator  operator++(int) { d_val++; return my_iterator(d_val - 1); }
  my_iterator &operator++()    { d_val++; return *this; }

  int operator*() const { return d_val; }

  bool operator==(my_iterator const  &o) { return d_val == o.d_val; }
  bool operator!=(my_iterator const  &o) { return d_val != o.d_val ; }
};


int main() {
  std::reverse_iterator<my_iterator> reverse_it_begin(25);
  std::reverse_iterator<my_iterator> reverse_it_end(12);
  std::for_each(reverse_it_begin, reverse_it_end, [](int e){ std::cout << e << ' '; });
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The iterator is immutable, since operator*() returns an *int* instead of a *int reference*. To the best of my understanding this is possible, since whether an iterator meets the BidirectionalIterator concept or the OutputIterator concept is orthogonal (all 4 combinations are possible).

However, the code below results in an compile time error, namely:

```cpp
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:164:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::reverse_iterator<my_iterator>::reference {aka int&}' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

Full context:

```cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::reference std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::operator*() const [with _Iterator = my_iterator; std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::reference = int&]':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:3755:6:   required from '_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = std::reverse_iterator<my_iterator>; _Funct = main()::<lambda(int)>]'
prog.cpp:30:86:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:164:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::reverse_iterator<my_iterator>::reference {aka int&}' from an rvalue of type 'int'
  return *--__tmp;
        ^

Success time: 0 mem
```

The pages on cppreference about the reverse_iterator and for_each state that both need a BidirectionalIterator and an InputIterator respectively. I think both requirements are met, however the stl still assigns a dereferenced value to a reference.

Why does stl's for_each/reverse_iterator expect a T &operator*() on an iterator that needs not to be an OutputIterator?

PS: The commented line can fix the problem by stating that references should be stored by value, very hacky of course.

Comment: `my_iterator` doesn't satisfy iterator requirements, one of which is that `operator*` return a reference.

Comment: True that, I'm assuming this is because references are faster than copies, when passing iterator values through all the stl-api (or other) facilities like std::copy, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iterator requirements for all iterators are listed in [iterator.iterators]:

[image]

`reference` refers to the typedef of `iterator_traits<my_iterator<..>>`:

> In the following sections, `a` and `b` denote values of type `X` or
>   `const X`, `difference_type` and **`reference` refer to the types**
>   `iterator_traits<X>::difference_type` and
>   **`iterator_traits<X>::reference`**, respectively, [..]

Since the primary template of `iterator_traits` just defaults the typedefs to the types defined in the template argument itself, we're talking about the `reference` typedef of `my_iterator` - and that one is inherited from the base `std::iterator<...>`, which defaults it to `T&`.
Your `operator*` returns an `int` though, which is certainly not `int&`.

Uncommenting your line is fine for InputIterators since `int` is convertible to `int`:

[image]

It fails for ForwardIterators though - [forward.iterators]/1:

> A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward
>   iterator if
>
> — if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`;
>   **if `X` is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`,**

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't require an OutputIterator. The problem is that your code violates a basic requirement for all input iterators<sup>*</sup>: `*r` must return `reference`<sup>**</sup>. Your code defines `my_iterator::reference` as `int &` (due to `std::iterator`'s default template argument), but `operator*` returns an `int`.

It is valid for `reference` to not actually be a reference type (`istreambuf_iterator<charT>::reference`, for example, is `charT`), but `operator*` must return `reference`. `reverse_iterator` relies on this, as it defines its `reference` member, and hence the return type of its `operator*`, as its wrapped iterator's `reference`.

According to the standard, for forward iterators or stronger, `reference` must be a reference type. But the standard itself lies when it calls `vector<bool>::iterator` a random access iterator (its `operator*` must return a proxy), and the committee is apparently planning to lie some more with the [`array_view` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4346.html). So while making `my_iterator::reference` `int` would mean that it is technically no longer a bidirectional iterator, in practice it's likely to work. Hopefully with Concepts we can get better and finer-grained requirements than what we currently have.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> There's a contradiction in the standard with respect to output iterators. See [LWG issue 2437](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2437).</sub>

<sub><sup>**</sup> Technically, `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference`. For class types, `iterator_traits` by default defers to the member typedef `It::reference`.</sub>

Comment: You fool.  Once you introduce one footnote, the floodgates are open.  Stop this madness!(1) --- (1) not actually madness.

Comment: To be exact, the `array_view` document says that "`bounds_iterator` satisfies the requirements of a random access iterator unless otherwise specified below."  Since "below" includes the declaration `using reference = const index<Rank>;`, `bounds_iterator` is clearly *not* a random access iterator, despite satisfying some of the other requirements. Of course its category is specified as "`using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;`", so **passing a `bounds_iterator` to any standard library function that accepts iterators invokes undefined behavior**. Great work, that.